bert-tokenizer to tokenize the sentence
how can i overcome to remove # signs when I am using ber-tokenizer
​
Tokens length: 200
Tokens: ['[CLS]', 'educational', 'background', 'computer', 'applications', 'masters', 'degree', 'software', 'along', 'strong', 'skills', 'p', '##yt', '##hon', 'sq', '##l', 'j', '##ava', 'l', '##in', '##ux', 'g', '##it', 'certification', 'cloud', 'computing', 'well', '##e', '##qui', '##pped', 'successful', 'career', 'tech', 'industry', 'given', 'interest', 'cloud', 'computing', 'could', 'ex', '##cel', 'roles', 'cloud', 'solutions', 'architect', 'cloud', 'engineer', 'de', '##vo', '##ps', 'engineer', 'leverage', 'skills', 'cloud', 'technologies', 'design', 'implement', 'manage', 'cloud', 'infrastructure', 'organizations', 'recommend', 'continuing', 'enhance', 'expertise', 'cloud', 'computing', 'pursuing', 'advanced', 'certification', '##s', 'like', 'a', '##ws', 'certified', 'solutions', 'architect', 'micro', '##so', '##ft', 'certified', 'a', '##zure', 'solutions', 'architect', 'expert', 'stand', 'competitive', 'tech', 'market', 'additionally', 'gaining', 'experience', 'real', '##world', 'cloud', 'projects', 'internship', '##s', 'freelance', 'opportunities', 'boost', 'profile', 'keep', 'networkin
I am tring this code using bert-tokenize
seq_length=200
tokens= tokenizer(df['answer'].tolist(),
                 max_length=seq_length,
                truncation=True,
                padding='max_length',
                add_special_tokens=True,
                return_tensors='np')

tokens have input_ids where i have seen some tokens are divided to subtokens and it may effect the whole results,
I want to expect only one token instead of sub tokens

This tokenization strategy is called word-piece and is very popular and powerful. I encourage you to use it... however if you wanted to tokenize per word, you would need to have a unique token for each word. To do this, you can simply one hot encode each word. The length of the vectors will be the total amount of unique words you support. Don't expect any pretrained model to be able to understand your new tokenization patterns as the performance of a transformer is conditional on the same tokenization strategy being used as during training.
